# AngularJS Selection - setting ng-model in controller does not update selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, data-binding, local-storage

I'm facing a problem in upgrading my ng-model in selection.
I have the following HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="viewmodel.inputDevice"
        ng-options="i.label for i in viewmodel.inputDevices">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following code:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
     // view model
    $scope.viewmodel = new function () {
        var self = this;
        var elem1 = {
            value: '1',
            label: 'input1'
        };

        var elem2 = {
            value: '2',
            label: 'input2'
        }

        self.inputDevices = [elem1, elem2];

        self.inputDevice = {
            value: '1',
            label: 'input1'
        };
    };
}
```

You can use the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ln/26/)

What I want to do is put in **inputDevice** the same values that the first device has in  the collection **inputDevices**.
I know that I can pass **elem1** and it will work however i can't do it since i want to save the selection in Local Storage and than restore it to the ng-model object.
Any suggestion will be grateful
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either store the value instead of the object as Maxim has demonstrated, or you can pull the correct value from the `inputDevices` array with something like:

```
self.inputDevice = self.inputDevices.filter(function(item) {
   return item.value == storedValue.value;
})[0];
```

as per [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ln/31/)

Answer (score 2):

The code in the original question works for me:

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="viewmodel.inputDevice"
      ng-options="i.label for i in viewmodel.inputDevices">
    </select>

    <!-- displays the initial and any further selections 
         correctly as : {"value":"1","label":"input1"} -->
    <span>{{viewmodel.inputDevice}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your js code code works no doubt, but the viewmodel can be build a little easier:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
 // view model
  $scope.viewmodel = {inputDevices: [
                      {value: '1', label: 'input1'}, 
                      {value: '2', label: 'input2'}
                    ]};
  $scope.viewmodel.inputDevice = $scope.viewmodel.inputDevices[0];
```

}

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ln/39/

Answer (score 1):

Instead:

```
self.inputDevice = {
            value: '1',
            label: 'input1'
        };
```

I would store index only:

```
 self.inputDevice = 0; // or 1 - second item
```

and:

```
    <select> 
        <option ng-repeat="i in viewmodel.inputDevices" 
                value="{{i.label}}" 
                ng-selected="viewmodel.inputDevices.indexOf(i) == viewmodel.inputDevice"
        >{{i.label}}</option>
    </select>
```

This way will work.

Fixed Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ln/29/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is helpful, however its not quite suitable for my needs since I need to save the all object and rely on its key and not index since the inputDevices collection is changed dynamically.